# Magento2.3: Products are not displaying at all in Category page

Tags: magento2.3, category, configurable-product, products

I have created a simple product and attached with one of the category. However, the product is not displaying at all when I go to the corresponding category page. I can only browse the product when I put the product URL.

While checking, all those things are set correctly, like stock, attached with category, website, anchor in category and show products only in category.

I'm not sure why the product is not displaying at all.

Comment: product visibility??

Comment: Yes that is also set to catalog search

Comment: product in stock? run indexer

Comment: Tried reindexing many times but still not working

Comment: yes try to iindexer:reindex and check

Comment: @RkRathod, I have done that but not success.

Comment: Are you using default theme with no customisations? Are you using mysql or elasticsearch for catalog search engine?

Comment: @paj, We have extended the luma theme and we are not using the elasticsearch for catalog search engine.

Comment: please share me product details snaps from admin edit, then I can check it.